# How to know enemies' health?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am trying to use commands as shown on [this page](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Console_Commands_(Skyrim)/ActorValues), specifically `getavinfo` while a dragon is right in front of me.
I get nothing back. Nothing shows up in the console or anything about the health of the dragon I am facing.

I want to see my opponents' level and health, how do I do so?

[This page](https://steamcommunity.com/app/72850/discussions/0/535152276588488882/) says I can get the value using `getav`. I click on the dragon - wait a minute, how do I click on the dragon? I have a crosshair: should I look at the dragon? Where will the number show?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I determine an NPC's level?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/124310/4797)

Comment: Could be. But I found a better solution anyway. No it doesn't. This question ask for health and that question ask for level. My answer answers both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: The easiest way to see enemies health is to install these mods

https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/12688

[image]

Another way is to use console but just check that mod above.

So, a dragon have 3k health. To get 100 one hand skill I will need like 500k xp. So around 100 dragons with normal bound sword.

Another way

I figured that out. Basically, press ~

After that I can click on the dragon and it'll show some numbers

[image]

There you go.

Comment: On PC if you need a better console check out [More Informative Console](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/19250).

Comment: @joachim answer is correct, but the mod is much better

Answer (score 2):

Once the console is brought up (using <kbd>~</kbd> (<kbd>`</kbd>) on PC, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> or <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> on MacOS), you can use your mouse to select currently visible entities.
As targeted commands control the active entity, always **be sure you are targeting the right object or NPC**, as entities overlap at times and it's hard to tell which one is active.

**To get an NPC's Health, select it and use the command `getAV Health`.**